# Removing all grid lines in Google Charts API

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using the Google Charts API to create a stepped area chart and I'd like to remove all horizontal lines in my chart. I've looked at all the documentation for the options, but I don't see any way to remove it. Is there some way to trick the API into removing them or am I stuck with them? The lines I am talking about is in the picture below, just to clear possible confusion.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following option...

```
vAxis: {
  gridlines: {
    count: 0
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Director (Year)',  'Rotten Tomatoes', 'IMDB'],
    ['Alfred Hitchcock (1935)', 8.4,         7.9],
    ['Ralph Thomas (1959)',     6.9,         6.5],
    ['Don Sharp (1978)',        6.5,         6.4],
    ['James Hawes (2008)',      4.4,         6.2]
  ]);

  var options = {
    isStacked: true,
    vAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        count: 0
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Weird, the docs say "The number of vertical gridlines inside the chart area. Minimum value is 2. Specify -1 to automatically compute the number of gridlines.". Minimum should be 2 but this is working?

Comment: It does work, I find it interesting that using the gridlines count for the vAxis, also affects the hAxis. I think that's why I was a little confused.

Answer (score 1):

Set `vAxis.gridlines.color` to transparent. You see more options in the [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart#configuration-options) section from the docs.

Use (using example from [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart)):

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Director (Year)', 'Rotten Tomatoes', 'IMDB'],
    ['Alfred Hitchcock (1935)', 8.4, 7.9],
    ['Ralph Thomas (1959)', 6.9, 6.5],
    ['Don Sharp (1978)', 6.5, 6.4],
    ['James Hawes (2008)', 4.4, 6.2]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'The decline of \'The 39 Steps\'',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Accumulated Rating',
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    },
    isStacked: true
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;"></div>
```